# How to write code to run a function and retrieve values from it

Tags: matlab, function

I am supposed to use a 2D Gaussian function which will have the following mathematical expression () = ^(−(−)^2/^2) and plot a graph of the function.   µ is the mean and std stands for the standard deviation, by the way.  How would a write code to plug in values to the function and output the values of G(x) and x in to an array to be plotted?

I've tried looking at older code I've done for previous graph's I've made, but this function is much more complex than I've ever done.

Answer (score 1):

The following anonymous function would work in your case

```
G = @(x,mu,sigma) exp(-((x-mu).^2)/(sigma^2));
x=-10:0.01:10;
plot(x,G(x,0.2,0.4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generically speaking, use the following method to call a function and return values:

Main Script

```
clc; clear; close all;
x = 0;
y = add_x(x);
```

Function Call

```
function y = add_x(x)
    y = x+1;
end
```

Read more about [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) calling in the MATLAB Documentation.